# Building a jni lib for tux rider android application

Tags: android, java-native-interface, loadlibrary, android-library

I've downloaded drodin's android app "Tux rider" source code, in order to build it my self.
https://github.com/drodin/TuxRider

in the application, there's a call for a library called "tuxrider"

```
System.loadLibrary("tuxrider");
```

but there's no such library, and I'm not managing to figure out how to build one from all the files there.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be build scripts for that library in TuxRider/jni/tuxrider. You'll probably need to download Android NDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) and read this page to build it: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html

Comment: I've already downloaded the NDK, but I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: Start the NDK command 'ndk-build' from the cmd/shell inside the tuxrider folder.

Comment: Still, it won't work, for some reason, I get this error.

    make: *** [/drodin-2/obj/local/armeabi/objs/tuxrider/src/alglib.o] Error 1

This follows a lot of other non-fatal errors.
could there be a problem with the already-given Android.mk?

Comment: that specific problem is caused by file extentions being in small letters and not big ones, i.e. file.c => file.C. very wierd

Comment: I did try to compile it, but it stopped on inconsistencies in the code (unknown variables, incompatible pointer types). However, I didn't see the problem you describe; maybe its a platform problem (I tried on macosx).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I menaged to solve a problem. It was caused by GoogleAds, not by `tuxrider` library. Simply, comment all mentioning of GoogleAds in `MainActivity.java`.
That includes:

```
//import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
//import com.google.ads.AdSize;
//import com.google.ads.AdView;
...
//  private static AdView mAdView = null;
...
//      mAdView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14d3678cfc9fb7");

//      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
//      adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

//      mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
//      mAdView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
...
//      mFrameLayout.addView(mAdView, new LayoutParams(
//              LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
...
//          if (mAdView != null) {
//              mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//          }
...
//          if (mAdView != null) {
//              mAdView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//          }
```

After this, all should work fine. Chears!