# Tux Rider compiles but crashes on startup

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, startup

I wanted to experiment with Android development, so I decided to mess around with drodin's Tux Rider app. I had to create a new project in Eclipse, as drodin's existing one wasn't recognized. From there, I copied and pasted the original project in. The app compiled just fine in Eclipse (once I downloaded the latest Google Ads SDK and replaced the missing, older version in the build path). The problem is, it crashes whenever I try to run it on a virtual Android 1.6 phone as well as a Nexus 7 with Android 4.2.2. When I attempted to use debug mode with the virtual phone, the app hung at the loading screen, then proceeded to crash when I closed Eclipse.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** Here's the LogCat log:
    http://pastebin.com/3jdHEbw2
And here's the traces.txt from data/anr:
    http://pastebin.com/x9vijEjm

Comment: Post your Stack Trace from LogCat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
07-18 04:26:30.696: W/dalvikvm(379): threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
07-18 04:26:30.705: E/AndroidRuntime(379): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-9 exiting due to uncaught exception
07-18 04:26:30.776: E/AndroidRuntime(379): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-18 04:26:30.776: E/AndroidRuntime(379):      at com.drodin.tuxrider.Installer.InstallFiles(Installer.java:54)
07-18 04:26:30.776: E/AndroidRuntime(379):      at com.drodin.tuxrider.Installer$1.run(Installer.java:41)
07-18 04:26:30.776: E/AndroidRuntime(379):      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)
07-18 04:26:30.776: E/AndroidRuntime(379): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library tuxrider not found
07-18 04:26:30.776: E/AndroidRuntime(379):      at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:489)
07-18 04:26:30.776: E/AndroidRuntime(379):      at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
07-18 04:26:30.776: E/AndroidRuntime(379):      at com.drodin.tuxrider.NativeLib.<clinit>(NativeLib.java:33)
07-18 04:26:30.776: E/AndroidRuntime(379):      ... 3 more
```

Specifically:

```
 at com.drodin.tuxrider.Installer.InstallFiles(Installer.java:54)
```

because of this:

```
07-18 04:26:30.776: E/AndroidRuntime(379): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library tuxrider not found)
```

It seems to be looking a library that you don't have in your project, or you may have it in your project, but you don't have it linked; somethings missing.

Under properties check the Java Build Path tab, make sure that Private Libraries are checked under 'Order and Export' also make sure you have anything necessary in your libs folder...

EDIT: It seems that there is an issue with the GoogleAds API as per this question [Building a JNI Lib for Tux Rider Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620059/building-a-jni-lib-for-tux-rider-android-appliction)

Comment out all the GoogleAds code in MainActivity.

Comment: Private Libraries is checked, Google Ads SDK and Android 1.6 are not. The only thing in my libs folder is android-support-v4.jar. I don't know what else I would put in the libs folder. Would it help to run the NDK first?

Comment: @user2593596 Found a specific solution for what seems to be the same problem. Edited answer.

Comment: I've seen that thread before. After commenting out the ad-related code and the line that asks for the 'tuxrider' library, the app still crashes, but this time because libhgl.so is missing. I suppose that means I will have to run the NDK.

Comment: I can confirm that using the NDK solved the problem with the 'tuxrider' library, but the problem still persists. Here's the new logcat log: pastebin.com/5qJHD84T. Looks like something to do with the resize command, and I have no clue how to fix it. Here's the NativeLib.java that the offending command is in: http://pastebin.com/bVTY0Xb2

Comment: It turns out hardware acceleration is essential for Tux Rider, so my emulator won't cut it (my netbook can't emulate hardware acceleration, imagine that). Running on real hardware works perfectly. Thanks for all your help, Tonithy!